# Kafka: Bounded Batch Processing in Parallel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, batch-processing, spring-cloud-stream

I would like to use Kafka to perform **bounded batch processing**, where the program will know when it is processing the last record.

Batch:

- Reading a flat file
- Send each line as message to Kafka

Kafka Listener:

- Consumes message from Kafka
- Insert record into database
- *If it is the last record, mark batch job as done in database.*

One way probably is to use a single Kafka partition, assuming FIFO (First In First Out) is guaranteed, and make the batch program to send an *isLastRecord* flag.

However, this means the processing will be restricted to single-thread (single consumer).

**Question**

Is there any way to achieve this with parallel-processing by leveraging multiple Kafka partitions?

Answer (score 2):

If you need in-order guarantees per file, you are restricted to a single partition.

If you have multiple files, you could use different partitions for different files though.

If each line in the file is an insert into a database, I am wondering though if you need in-order guarantee in the first place, or if you can insert all records/lines in any order?

A more fundamental question is: why do you need to put the data into Kafka first? Why not read the file and to the insert directly?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, it can be inserted in any order, but I need to know when all the records has been processed, thus I need to be able to detect the "last" record.

Comment: If you know how many partitions you have, you should be able to write an "end-of-batch" marker into each partition, and count the number of "processed" markers to determine if all data was inserted?

Comment: The intention to put it into Kafka is to allow the parallel processing using multiple instances of Kafka listeners, for the sake of scalability. Just want to explore the possibility.

Comment: Perhaps a traditional message queue with competing consumers might be a better choice. With other queuing technologies like RabbitMQ, SQS etc, you can have a single queue and multiple consumers. With Kafka you cannot do this as you have the one consumer per partition limit.

Comment: Just to add an update, you can now subdivide a Kafka partition and process it as concurrently as you like, using Confluent Parallel Consumer (https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer).